# DrawText on Windows Title Bar no longer works

Tags: windows, winapi, titlebar, nonclient-area

In order to write some text at the right hand end of the title bar, my program catches `WM_NCPAINT`, gets the device context, calculates the position to write the text and then calls `DrawText`. This code used to work, but with Windows 8 and Windows 10, it no longer works. It would appear you simply cannot paint onto the title bar in these newer versions of Windows.

The device context is obtained as follows using Win API (not MFC):-

```
HDC hDC = GetWindowDC(hwnd);
```

which is described in [Windows Dev Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowdc) thus:-

> The **GetWindowDC** function retrieves the device context (DC) for the entire window, including title bar, menus, and scroll bars. A window device context permits painting anywhere in a window, because the origin of the device context is the upper-left corner of the window instead of the client area.

There is no mention of this function being Windows version specific, but what it describes simply no longer works. Replacing the call to `DrawText` with a big black rectangle (-300,-300,1000,1000) leaves the title bar beautifully untouched showing that painting the entire window rectangle is not possible.

I have tried instead obtaining the device context as follows:-

```
HDC hDC = GetDCEx(hwnd, (HRGN)wParam, DCX_WINDOW|DCX_INTERSECTRGN);
```

as described in the [documentation for `WM_NCPAINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/gdi/wm-ncpaint). So long as the window class is registered with one of `CS_CLASSDC`, `CS_OWNDC` or `CS_PARENTDC`, then an `hDC` is returned (if not zero is returned). But this `hDC` has exactly the same issue.

I tried a variation on the above, because the clipping seemed dubious. I tried:-

```
HDC hDC = GetDCEx(hwnd, 0, DCX_WINDOW);
```

after all the documentation says of `DCX_WINDOW`:-

> **Value:** DCX_WINDOW
>
> **Meaning:** Returns a DC that corresponds to the window rectangle rather than the client rectangle.

This device context demonstrates the same behaviour too.

How do I obtain a device context that allows me to `DrawText` or indeed draw anything, on the title bar?

Comment: @OlafHess - I'm not using MFC which is the API mentioned in that question

Comment: Doesn't matter, MFC is just a very light shell around Win32

Comment: As a WinAPI user searching for answers to this problem, I didn't find the MFC examples because I am not using that API. While the answer link may be the same, the question search is different.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Vista introduced the Aero theme and with it the [Desktop Windows Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dwm/dwm-overview):
*The desktop composition feature, introduced in Windows Vista, fundamentally changed the way applications display pixels on the screen. When desktop composition is enabled, individual windows no longer draw directly to the screen or primary display device as they did in previous versions of Windows. Instead, their drawing is redirected to off-screen surfaces in video memory, which are then rendered into a desktop image and presented on the display.*

The article [Custom Window Frame Using DWM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dwm/customframe) demonstrates how to use the Desktop Window Manager (DWM) APIs to create custom window frames for your application. This includes drawing text on a window's title bar. Windows Vista and Windows 7 allowed the user to turn the Aero theme off to allow a program to manipulate a program's title bar the same way as in XP and earlier versions. Starting with Windows 8, desktop composition is always enabled.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out. I have submitted feedback on the WM_NCPAINT Windows Doc page to tell them it is out of date. Whether anything happens as a result on that will remain to be seen.